# How to load multiple symbol files in gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

How to load multiple symbol files in `gdb`. I have a executable foo.out and loading a module bar.so. I have created two symbol files foo.symbol and bar.symbol. How to load both the files into gdb.

```
# gdb --core core
# (gdb) 
# (gdb) symbol-file foo.symbol
```

How to load the second symbol file. Or is there any way to load all the files of directory in `gdb`

Answer (score 40):

To set the directory containing symbol file use

```
set debug-file-directory <directory>
```

and use

```
show debug-file-directory
```

to show what currently is set as directory containing symbol files.

Symbol files are read automagically from this directory if their name (without path) is provided by the binary in terms of a debug-link.

---

To add additional symbols you might use `add-symbol-file`.

(as the [gdb onlinedocs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/) seem to be unavailable at the moment I quote this here)

> add-symbol-file filename address
>
> add-symbol-file filename address [ -readnow ] [ -mapped ]
>
> add-symbol-file filename -ssection address ...
>
> The add-symbol-file command reads additional symbol table information from the file filename. You would use this command when filename has been dynamically loaded (by some other means) into the program that is running. address should be the memory address at which the file has been loaded; gdb cannot figure this out for itself. You can additionally specify an arbitrary number of `-ssection address' pairs, to give an explicit section name and base address for that section. You can specify any address as an expression.
>
> The symbol table of the file filename is added to the symbol table originally read with the symbol-file command. You can use the add-symbol-file command any number of times; the new symbol data thus read keeps adding to the old. To discard all old symbol data instead, use the symbol-file command without any arguments.
>
> Although filename is typically a shared library file, an executable file, or some other object file which has been fully relocated for loading into a process, you can also load symbolic information from relocatable .o files, as long as:
>
> - the file's symbolic information refers only to linker symbols defined in that file, not to symbols defined by other object files,
> - every section the file's symbolic information refers to has actually been loaded into the inferior, as it appears in the file, and
> - you can determine the address at which every section was loaded, and provide these to the add-symbol-file command.
>
> Some embedded operating systems, like Sun Chorus and VxWorks, can load relocatable files into an already running program; such systems typically make the requirements above easy to meet. However, it's important to recognize that many native systems use complex link procedures (.linkonce section factoring and C++ constructor table assembly, for example) that make the requirements difficult to meet. In general, one cannot assume that using add-symbol-file to read a relocatable object file's symbolic information will have the same effect as linking the relocatable object file into the program in the normal way.
>
> add-symbol-file does not repeat if you press  after using it.
>
> You can use the `-mapped' and`-readnow' options just as with the symbol-file command, to change how gdb manages the symbol table information for filename.

Comment: I tried that but it is not loading the symbol files from said directory

Comment: Do you load bar.so dynamically? Does it contian a debug link?

Comment: Yes bar.so is linking dynamically and does not contain the symbols. I have symbol file of bar.symbol

Comment: gdb cannot figure this out the address, how can I know the address?

Comment: In my case gdb searched not in the directory set to debug-file-directory itself, but in a subdirectory, which is the absolute path to the original file (bar.so).

Answer (score 29):

Additional symbols can be loaded to the `gdb` debug session with:

```
add-symbol-file filename address
```

Parameter `address` is the address for `.text` section. This address can be retrieved with:

```
readelf -WS path/to/file.elf | grep .text | awk '{ print "0x"$5 }'
```

This can be automated in `gdb` by adding following entry to `~/.gdbinit`:

```
define add-symbol-file-auto
  # Parse .text address to temp file
  shell echo set \$text_address=$(readelf -WS $arg0 | grep .text | awk '{ print "0x"$5 }') >/tmp/temp_gdb_text_address.txt

  # Source .text address
  source /tmp/temp_gdb_text_address.txt

  #  Clean tempfile
  shell rm -f /tmp/temp_gdb_text_address.txt

  # Load symbol table
  add-symbol-file $arg0 $text_address
end
```

After above function definition `add-symbol-file-auto` can be used load additional symbols:

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file-auto path/to/bootloader.elf
add symbol table from file "path/to/bootloader.elf" at
    .text_addr = 0x8010400
(gdb) add-symbol-file-auto path/to/application.elf
add symbol table from file "path/to/application.elf" at
    .text_addr = 0x8000000
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8006cb0: main. (2 locations)
(gdb) info break
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   <MULTIPLE> 
1.1                         y     0x08006cb0 in main() at ./source/main.cpp:114
1.2                         y     0x080106a6 in main() at ./main.cpp:10
(gdb)
```

Comment: Here is a version of `add-symbol-file-auto` that does not depend on a temporary file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380204/how-to-load-multiple-symbol-files-in-gdb/62471062#62471062

Comment: Very nice @rob-w thanks very much.

Answer (score 12):

In addition of the alk's answer and its comments, the address asked is the address of the `.text` section.
You can find it by using the `readelf` command

Here you have an example of a `readelf` use for binary files [The address where filename has been loaded is missing [GDB]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508357/the-address-where-filename-has-been-loaded-is-missing-gdb)

Answer (score 7):

`add-symbol-file-auto` from [Jaakko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55744855/938089) relies on writing to an external file. This can cause issues if the file cannot be read or written. Here is an implementation that offers the same functionality, using a [GDB command defined in Python](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Commands-In-Python.html). Add this to your `.gdbinit`:

```python
python
# Note: Replace "readelf" with path to binary if it is not in your PATH.
READELF_BINARY = 'readelf'

class AddSymbolFileAuto (gdb.Command):
    """Load symbols from FILE, assuming FILE has been dynamically loaded (auto-address).
Usage: add-symbol-file-auto FILE [-readnow | -readnever]
The necessary starting address of the file's text is resolved by 'readelf'."""
    def __init__(self):
        super(AddSymbolFileAuto, self).__init__("add-symbol-file-auto", gdb.COMMAND_FILES)

    def invoke(self, solibpath, from_tty):
        from os import path
        self.dont_repeat()
        if os.path.exists(solibpath) == False:
            print ("{0}: No such file or directory." .format(solibpath))
            return
        offset = self.get_text_offset(solibpath)
        gdb_cmd = "add-symbol-file %s %s" % (solibpath, offset)
        gdb.execute(gdb_cmd, from_tty)

    def get_text_offset(self, solibpath):
        import subprocess
        elfres = subprocess.check_output([READELF_BINARY, "-WS", solibpath])
        for line in elfres.splitlines():
            if "] .text " in line:
                return "0x" + line.split()[4]
        return ""  # TODO: Raise error when offset is not found?

    def complete(self, text, word):
        return gdb.COMPLETE_FILENAME

AddSymbolFileAuto()
end
```

Usage example:

```
add-symbol-file-auto foo.symbol
```

Note that merely loading the symbols with [`add-symbol-file`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html#index-dynamic-linking) can allow you to set breakpoints, but this does not automatically mean that you can do something useful with it, such as actually triggering the breakpoint. Use [`info sharedlibrary`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html#index-info-share) (or `info shared`) to verify that the symbols are actually relevant to the debugging target (optionally with a pattern to show specific results instead of all). It should look like this:

```
(gdb) gdb-symbol-file-auto path/to/library.symbols
(gdb) info shared symbol-file
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x0000abc0  0x0000def0  Yes         path/to/library
```

The following is shown when the loaded symbols are not used:

```
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x0000abc0  0x0000def0  Yes (*)     path/to/library
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
```

The following is shown when GDB is unable to load the library at all (e.g. [if GDB has a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62468510/938089)):

```
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x0000abc0  0x0000def0  No          path/to/library
```

Comment: +1, good to have this here. I don't like the tempfile either. I remember looking at Python but I think there was some limitation using python with that specific gdb version.

Comment: I've found this script very useful and adjusted it a bit to match `add-symbol-file`, hoping @rob-w doesn't mind: added help, moved to gdb files (it will be shown next to add-symbol-file in GDB's help), added don't-repeat, added file exist check (for the original one please see the edit).
Note: instead of added to `.gdbinit` this may also by included in anyfile and then `source anyfile` and/or can be moved to anyfile.py with `source anyfile.py` - in which case the first line `python` and last line `end` are removed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of attempting to load symbols manually into the correct location I have found it more convenient to [merge the symbols back to the stripped executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977961/how-to-undo-strip-i-e-add-symbols-back-to-stripped-binary/49035838#49035838) with `eu-unstrip` and then reproduce the crash with symbols already present.

This approach does not depend on symbol files matching the naming scheme required by the path resolution mechanisms (*debug link* and *build id*) that get used when you set `debug-file-directory`.

Answer (score 0):

While debugging core files, I found that the address obtained using readelf (as mentioned in other answers here) doesn't load the symbols files for shared libraries properly when `add-symbol-file` command is used.

I instead needed to use the '*From*' address shown in command `info sharedlibrary`/ `info shared <libname>`:

```
(gdb) info shared libcore
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x0f24caa0  0x0f41c280  Yes (*)     /lib/libcore.so
```

After using this address and loading the symbol file, I was able to get line numbers properly.

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file libcore.so.debug 0x0f24caa0
add symbol table from file "libcore.so.debug" at
    .text_addr = 0xf24caa0
(y or n) y
Reading symbols from libcore.so.debug...
```

I found this solution after reading this page: [Creating and using debug symbol tables with CMake and GDB](https://medium.com/@ffugavr/creating-and-using-debug-symbol-tables-with-cmake-and-gdb-7554868d51ea)

Answer (score -2):

```
add-symbol-file filename address
add-symbol-file filename address [ -readnow ] [ -mapped ]
add-symbol-file filename -ssection address ...
```

see http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_125.html