# The address where filename has been loaded is missing [GDB]

Tags: linux, gdb, memory-address

I have following sample code

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
      int num1, num2;
      printf("Enter two numbers\n");
      scanf("%d",&num1);
      scanf("%d",&num2);
      int i;
      for(i = 0; i < num2; i++)
        num1 = num1 + num1;
      printf("Result is %d \n",num1);
          return 0;
    }
```

I compiled this code with -g option to gcc.

```
gcc -g file.c
```

Generate separate symbol file

```
objcopy --only-keep-debug a.out a.out.sym
```

Strip the symbols from a.out

```
strip -s a.out
```

Load this a.out in gdb

```
gdb a.out
```

gdb says "no debug information found" fine.
Then I use *add-symbol-file* command in gdb

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file a.out.debug [Enter]
The address where a.out.debug has been loaded is missing
```

- I want to know how to find this *address*?
- Is there any command or trick to find it?
- This *address* is representing WHAT?

I know gdb has an other command *symbol-file* but it overwrites the previous loaded symbols.
So I have to use this command to add **many symbol files** in gdb.
my system is 64bit running ubuntu LTS 12.04
gdb version is 7.4-2012.04
gcc version is 4.6.3

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> objcopy --only-keep-debug a.out a.out.sym

If you want GDB to load the a.out.sym *automatically*, follow the steps outlined [here](http://kb.roguewave.com/kb/?View=entry&EntryID=1470&Msg=) (note in particular that you need to do the "add `.gnu_debuglink`" step).

> This address is representing WHAT

The address GDB wants is the location of `.text` section of the binary. To find it, use `readelf -WS a.out`. E.g.

```
$ readelf -WS /bin/date
There are 28 section headers, starting at offset 0xe350:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        0000000000400238 000238 00001c 00   A  0   0  1
...
  [13] .text             PROGBITS        0000000000401900 001900 0077f8 00  AX  0   0 16
```

Here, you want to give GDB `0x401900` as the load address.

Comment: (you can also use `| grep '.text'` to extract only that line)