# How to generate core dump file with complete back trace for C++ application in CentOS 7

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, gdb, coredump

I am using `-std=c++0x -g3 -O0 –Wall` option in `CMakeLists.make` file and when segmentation fault is happening core dump file is generated.

When I open the core dump file using gdb it shows the crash location but not the complete back trace.

But when I am running my C++ application with gdb and segmentation fault is happening, using "bt" command I am getting complete back trace.

Can anyone please tell me how can I get the complete back trace of the crash location?

Comment: [How to load multiple symbol files in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20380204/608639). Once you load the core file with the `file` command you may need to tell gdb where its symbols are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to analyze a program's core dump file with gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305866/how-to-analyze-a-programs-core-dump-file-with-gdb)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the complete backtrace using below gdb command.

$ gdb -batch -ex "backtrace" "Binary path core" "dump file path"