# Debug with gdb an application running with different libc (ld-linux.so)

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, dynamic-loading

I would like to debug with *gdb* an app on an embedded system. This app requires a newer *glibc*, threading and works correctly by invoking the Linux dynamic loader `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. What I would like is to attach *gdb* and see the symbols and stack trace, but the loader "interferes" with *gdb*.

Here's a sample `test.c` file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *subThread(void *arg) {
        printf("Thread started after '%d' chars.\n", (long *)arg);
        sleep(2);
        printf("Thread '%d' ended.\n", (long *)arg);
        pthread_exit(NULL);

}
int main() {
        pid_t pid = getpid();
        if (pid > 0) {
                printf("The process id is %d.\n", pid);
                printf("Type 'q' to exit, 't' to spawn a thread.\n");

                char readChar;
                long count = 0;
                do {
                        count++;
                        readChar = getchar();
                        if (readChar == 't') {
                                // Spawn a thread
                                pthread_t thread_id;
                                pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, subThread, (void *) count);
                                pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
                        }
                } while(readChar != 'q');

                printf("Main ended.\n");
                return(0);
        } else {
                return(1);
        }
}
```

I compile this source file in a system with a specific *glibc* version like so:

```sh
othersystem:~# gcc -O2 -g -lpthread -o test test.c
```

Then I move the `test` binary file into my embedded system, that has an **older *glibc*** version and that cannot run `test` directly, so I'm copying the loader and the required libraries too. See also my *gdb* settings.

```sh
[~/test] # ls
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2*  libc.so.6*  libpthread.so.0*  libthread_db.so.1  test*

[~/test] # cat ~/.gdbinit 
set auto-load safe-path /
set pagination off
set libthread-db-search-path /root/test
```

Now I run the code and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to pause and **I want to attach *gdb*** using the process id. The problem is that *gdb* sees the loader instead of the application and doesn't load the debug symbols.

```sh
[~/test] # /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /root/test /root/test/test 
The process id is 30622.
Type 'q' to exit, 't' to spawn a thread.
^Z
[1]+  Stopped(SIGTSTP)        /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /root/test /root/test/test

[~/test] # gdb /root/test/test 30622
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.1
Reading symbols from /root/test/test...
Attaching to program: /root/test/test, process 30622

warning: Build ID mismatch between current exec-file /root/test/test
and automatically determined exec-file /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
exec-file-mismatch handling is currently "ask"
Load new symbol table from "/root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"? (y or n) y
Reading symbols from /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...
(No debugging symbols found in /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
Reading symbols from /root/test/libpthread.so.0...
(No debugging symbols found in /root/test/libpthread.so.0)
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/root/test/libthread_db.so.1".
Reading symbols from /root/test/libc.so.6...
(No debugging symbols found in /root/test/libc.so.6)
Reading symbols from /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...
(No debugging symbols found in /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
Reading symbols from /lib/libgcc_s.so.1...
0x00007fa1ef590494 in read () from /root/test/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fa1ef590494 in read () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fa1ef522670 in _IO_file_underflow () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fa1ef5237b2 in _IO_default_uflow () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007fa1ef51de68 in getc () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007fa1ef68b110 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007fa1ef68b290 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fa1ef4a2700 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007ffcdae50bb8 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I do not know how to tell *gdb* to load symbols from `/root/test/test`; there are interesting articles [here](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Debugging/Loader_Debugging#Debugging_With_an_Alternate_Loader) and [here](https://groups.google.com/g/gnu.gcc.help/c/EQyHkCF5QGo) and also [an answer on StackOveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55744855/2631300), but none worked... I'm not able to get the correct address to use the `add-symbol-file` directive.
I've tried like so:

```sh
[~/test] # cat /proc/30622/maps | grep "r-xp" | grep "/root/test/test" | awk -F'-' '{printf $1}'
7fa1ef68b000

[~/test] # objdump -s --section=".text" /root/test/test | grep Contents -A 1 | tail -n 1 | awk -F' ' '{printf $1}'                      
10c0
```

So the address should be **0x7fa1ef68b000** + **0x10c0** = **0x7fa1ef68c0c0**, right? But when I type this into *gdb*, you can see that it doesn't pick up the debug symbols:

```sh
(gdb) add-symbol-file /root/test/test 0x7fa1ef68c0c0
add symbol table from file "/root/test/test" at
        .text_addr = 0x7fa1ef68c0c0
(y or n) y
Reading symbols from /root/test/test...
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fa1ef590494 in read () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fa1ef522670 in _IO_file_underflow () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fa1ef5237b2 in _IO_default_uflow () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007fa1ef51de68 in getc () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007fa1ef68b110 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007fa1ef68b290 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fa1ef4a2700 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007ffcdae50bb8 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Is there a way to load the debug symbols without manually specifying the address? If I compile the binary to have the interpreter path hardcoded, like so:

```sh
othersystem:~# gcc -O2 -g -lpthread -Wl,-rpath /root/test -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o test2 test.c
```

Then all is working right:

```sh
[~/test] # ldd /root/test/test2
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcaa59c000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /root/test/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7265e1d000)
        libc.so.6 => /root/test/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7265c5c000)
        /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7265e40000)

[~/test] # /root/test/test2
The process id is 23264.
Type 'q' to exit, 't' to spawn a thread.
^Z
[1]+  Stopped(SIGTSTP)        ./test2

[~/test] # gdb /root/test/test2 23264
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.1
Reading symbols from /root/test/test2...
Attaching to program: /root/test/test2, process 23264
Reading symbols from /root/test/libpthread.so.0...
(No debugging symbols found in /root/test/libpthread.so.0)
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/root/test/libthread_db.so.1".
Reading symbols from /root/test/libc.so.6...
(No debugging symbols found in /root/test/libc.so.6)
Reading symbols from /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...
(No debugging symbols found in /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)

Program received signal SIGTSTP, Stopped (user).
0x00007ffba4e7d461 in read () from /root/test/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffba4e7d461 in read () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffba4e0f670 in _IO_file_underflow () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffba4e107b2 in _IO_default_uflow () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#3  0x00005613ef88a110 in getchar () at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio.h:49
#4  main () at test.c:24
```

### EDIT

As asked by Employed Russian, I'm adding the complete output of the maps and readelf (of course I had to use a new pid):

```sh
[~/test] # /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /root/test /root/test/test 
The process id is 16873.
Type 'q' to exit, 't' to spawn a thread.
^Z
[1]+  Stopped(SIGTSTP)        /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /root/test /root/test/test

[~/test] # cat /proc/16873/maps
7f5e3767b000-7f5e3767e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5e3767e000-7f5e376a0000 r--p 00000000 00:10 64323010                   /root/test/libc.so.6
7f5e376a0000-7f5e377e8000 r-xp 00022000 00:10 64323010                   /root/test/libc.so.6
7f5e377e8000-7f5e37834000 r--p 0016a000 00:10 64323010                   /root/test/libc.so.6
7f5e37834000-7f5e37835000 ---p 001b6000 00:10 64323010                   /root/test/libc.so.6
7f5e37835000-7f5e37839000 r--p 001b6000 00:10 64323010                   /root/test/libc.so.6
7f5e37839000-7f5e3783b000 rw-p 001ba000 00:10 64323010                   /root/test/libc.so.6
7f5e3783b000-7f5e3783f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5e3783f000-7f5e37845000 r--p 00000000 00:10 64323011                   /root/test/libpthread.so.0
7f5e37845000-7f5e37854000 r-xp 00006000 00:10 64323011                   /root/test/libpthread.so.0
7f5e37854000-7f5e3785a000 r--p 00015000 00:10 64323011                   /root/test/libpthread.so.0
7f5e3785a000-7f5e3785b000 r--p 0001a000 00:10 64323011                   /root/test/libpthread.so.0
7f5e3785b000-7f5e3785c000 rw-p 0001b000 00:10 64323011                   /root/test/libpthread.so.0
7f5e3785c000-7f5e37862000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5e37862000-7f5e37863000 r--p 00000000 00:10 64323013                   /root/test/test
7f5e37863000-7f5e37864000 r-xp 00001000 00:10 64323013                   /root/test/test
7f5e37864000-7f5e37865000 r--p 00002000 00:10 64323013                   /root/test/test
7f5e37865000-7f5e37866000 r--p 00002000 00:10 64323013                   /root/test/test
7f5e37866000-7f5e37867000 rw-p 00003000 00:10 64323013                   /root/test/test
7f5e37867000-7f5e37868000 r--p 00000000 00:10 64323009                   /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7f5e37868000-7f5e37886000 r-xp 00001000 00:10 64323009                   /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7f5e37886000-7f5e3788e000 r--p 0001f000 00:10 64323009                   /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7f5e3788e000-7f5e3788f000 r--p 00026000 00:10 64323009                   /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7f5e3788f000-7f5e37890000 rw-p 00027000 00:10 64323009                   /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7f5e37890000-7f5e37891000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5e3905f000-7f5e39080000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7fff1fcd3000-7fff1fcf4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff1fd82000-7fff1fd85000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fff1fd85000-7fff1fd87000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

[~/test] # readelf -Wl /root/test/test

Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x1160
There are 11 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x000268 0x000268 R   0x8
  INTERP         0x0002a8 0x00000000000002a8 0x00000000000002a8 0x00001c 0x00001c R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000768 0x000768 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000 0x0002fd 0x0002fd R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x002000 0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000 0x000210 0x000210 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x002dd8 0x0000000000003dd8 0x0000000000003dd8 0x000290 0x0002a8 RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x002de8 0x0000000000003de8 0x0000000000003de8 0x0001f0 0x0001f0 RW  0x8
  NOTE           0x0002c4 0x00000000000002c4 0x00000000000002c4 0x000044 0x000044 R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x002098 0x0000000000002098 0x0000000000002098 0x000044 0x000044 R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x002dd8 0x0000000000003dd8 0x0000000000003dd8 0x000228 0x000228 R   0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt 
   03     .init .plt .plt.got .text .fini 
   04     .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   05     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   06     .dynamic 
   07     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   08     .eh_frame_hdr 
   09     
   10     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got

[~/test] # readelf -WS /root/test/test
There are 37 section headers, starting at offset 0x4b18:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        00000000000002a8 0002a8 00001c 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            00000000000002c4 0002c4 000020 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 3] .note.gnu.build-id NOTE            00000000000002e4 0002e4 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        0000000000000308 000308 000028 00   A  5   0  8
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM          0000000000000330 000330 000168 18   A  6   1  8
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB          0000000000000498 000498 0000da 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM          0000000000000572 000572 00001e 02   A  5   0  2
  [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED         0000000000000590 000590 000040 00   A  6   2  8
  [ 9] .rela.dyn         RELA            00000000000005d0 0005d0 0000d8 18   A  5   0  8
  [10] .rela.plt         RELA            00000000000006a8 0006a8 0000c0 18  AI  5  23  8
  [11] .init             PROGBITS        0000000000001000 001000 000017 00  AX  0   0  4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS        0000000000001020 001020 000090 10  AX  0   0 16
  [13] .plt.got          PROGBITS        00000000000010b0 0010b0 000008 08  AX  0   0  8
  [14] .text             PROGBITS        00000000000010c0 0010c0 000231 00  AX  0   0 16
  [15] .fini             PROGBITS        00000000000012f4 0012f4 000009 00  AX  0   0  4
  [16] .rodata           PROGBITS        0000000000002000 002000 000097 00   A  0   0  8
  [17] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS        0000000000002098 002098 000044 00   A  0   0  4
  [18] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        00000000000020e0 0020e0 000130 00   A  0   0  8
  [19] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      0000000000003dd8 002dd8 000008 08  WA  0   0  8
  [20] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      0000000000003de0 002de0 000008 08  WA  0   0  8
  [21] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         0000000000003de8 002de8 0001f0 10  WA  6   0  8
  [22] .got              PROGBITS        0000000000003fd8 002fd8 000028 08  WA  0   0  8
  [23] .got.plt          PROGBITS        0000000000004000 003000 000058 08  WA  0   0  8
  [24] .data             PROGBITS        0000000000004058 003058 000010 00  WA  0   0  8
  [25] .bss              NOBITS          0000000000004070 003068 000010 00  WA  0   0 16
  [26] .comment          PROGBITS        0000000000000000 003068 00001c 01  MS  0   0  1
  [27] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        0000000000000000 003084 000040 00      0   0  1
  [28] .debug_info       PROGBITS        0000000000000000 0030c4 000626 00      0   0  1
  [29] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        0000000000000000 0036ea 000200 00      0   0  1
  [30] .debug_line       PROGBITS        0000000000000000 0038ea 00020c 00      0   0  1
  [31] .debug_str        PROGBITS        0000000000000000 003af6 000308 01  MS  0   0  1
  [32] .debug_loc        PROGBITS        0000000000000000 003dfe 0000e8 00      0   0  1
  [33] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS        0000000000000000 003ee6 000090 00      0   0  1
  [34] .symtab           SYMTAB          0000000000000000 003f78 000780 18     35  52  8
  [35] .strtab           STRTAB          0000000000000000 0046f8 0002bc 00      0   0  1
  [36] .shstrtab         STRTAB          0000000000000000 0049b4 000160 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  l (large), p (processor specific)
```

### FINAL SOLUTION

For an easier (future) reading, I'm reporting here the output after Employed Russian's solution.

```sh
[~/test] # /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /root/test /root/test/test 
The process id is 16873.
Type 'q' to exit, 't' to spawn a thread.
^Z
[1]+  Stopped(SIGTSTP)        /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /root/test /root/test/test

[~/test] # cat /proc/16873/maps | grep "/root/test/test" | awk -F'-' '{print "0x" $1; exit; }'
0x7f5e37862000
[~/test] # readelf -WS /root/test/test | grep '\.text ' | awk '{print "0x" $5}'
0x0010c0

[~/test] # gdb /root/test/test 16873
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.1
Reading symbols from /root/test/test...
Attaching to program: /root/test/test, process 16873

warning: Build ID mismatch between current exec-file /root/test/test
and automatically determined exec-file /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
exec-file-mismatch handling is currently "ask"
Load new symbol table from "/root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"? (y or n) y
Reading symbols from /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...
(No debugging symbols found in /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
Reading symbols from /root/test/libpthread.so.0...
(No debugging symbols found in /root/test/libpthread.so.0)
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/root/test/libthread_db.so.1".
Reading symbols from /root/test/libc.so.6...
(No debugging symbols found in /root/test/libc.so.6)
Reading symbols from /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...
(No debugging symbols found in /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)

Program received signal SIGTTIN, Stopped (tty input).
0x00007f5e37768461 in read () from /root/test/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f5e37768461 in read () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f5e376fa670 in _IO_file_underflow () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f5e376fb7b2 in _IO_default_uflow () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f5e37863110 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f5e37863290 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007f5e37863160 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fff1fcf2578 in ?? ()
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

(gdb) add-symbol-file /root/test/test 0x7f5e37862000+0x0010c0
add symbol table from file "/root/test/test" at
        .text_addr = 0x7f5e378630c0
(y or n) y
Reading symbols from /root/test/test...

(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f5e37768461 in read () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f5e376fa670 in _IO_file_underflow () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f5e376fb7b2 in _IO_default_uflow () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f5e37863110 in getchar () at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio.h:49
#4  main () at test.c:24
#5  0x00007f5e376a209b in __libc_start_main () from /root/test/libc.so.6
#6  0x00007f5e3786318a in _start ()

(gdb) q
A debugging session is active.

        Inferior 1 [process 16873] will be detached.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
Detaching from program: /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, process 16873
[Inferior 1 (process 16873) detached]

[1]+  Stopped(SIGTTIN)        /root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /root/test /root/test/test
```

So I have to reply <kbd>Y</kbd> to the request of the file mismatch and then `add-symbol-file` with the path of the real executable followed by the address (base + offset) retrieved using `/proc/pid/maps` (first result) and `readelf`.

Comment: What is the config/distro of your local and remote systems? To get symbols for `gdb`, depending on distro, you have to install the corresponding "debug" packages. On fedora, at least, `gdb` will, if it finds a `.so` without the debug info, will print the name of the debug package to install. BTW, you're doing a _native_ build on your local sys and then copying over the libs. Perhaps you should copy over the [old] lib files from remote to local and do a _cross_ build [even if it's the same arch]. If the remote were `arm`, you'd _have_ to do that.

Comment: @CraigEstey My problem is not getting the symbols from the debug package, because when I run the `test2` sample (which has the interpreter `/root/test/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` hardcoded) _gdb_ works and load my test app symbols. The question is about how to tell _gdb_ to load the app debug symbols when the app is [run from another loader](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Debugging/Loader_Debugging#Debugging_With_an_Alternate_Loader) and gdb is *attached* to its process id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but none worked...

The `add-symbol-file ...` solution *should* work. I suspect you are not supplying correct `.text` address.

> `cat /proc/30622/maps | grep "r-xp" | grep "/root/test/test"`

This assumes that the very first segment of `/root/test/test` has `RX` permissions.

That used to be the case, but no longer is on modern systems (see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57841768/50617)).

You didn't provide output from `readelf -Wl /root/test/test`, but I bet it looks similar to the 4-segment example from the other answer (with the first `LOAD` segment having `R`ead only permissions.

Generally you need to find the address of the first `LOAD` segment of the `test` executable in memory, and add the address of `.text` to *that* base address.

**Update:**

With the newly-supplied output from `/proc/$pid/maps` and `readelf`, we can see that my guess was correct: this binary has 4 `LOAD` segments, and the first one doesn't have `r-x` permissions.

The calculation then is: `$address_of_the_first_PT_LOAD + $address_of_.text`. That is (for the 16873 process):

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file /root/test/test 0x7f5e37862000+0x10c0
```

> `objdump -s --section=".text" /root/test/test | grep Contents -A 1 ...`

This is unnecessarily convoluted. Much easier way:

```
readelf -WS /root/test/test | grep '\.text ' | nawk '{print "0x" $4}'
```

**Update:**

> I need to run gdb in the test machine (which doesn't have nawk and other bells

Part of the difficulty here is that you have a PIE binary (relocated at runtime).

If the problem reproduces for non-PIE binary (built with `-fno-pie -no-pie`), then the address can be calculated once (e.g. on the development machine) and reused on the test machine. You wouldn't need a script to compute the address every time you run the binary.

---

> If I compile the binary to have the interpreter path hardcoded

Generally that's the best approach. Why not use it?

If you want the binary to run both on the development and the test machine, make copies of `/root/test` available on both.

Comment: I've updated the question with the full output of _/proc/pid/maps_ and _readelf_ as you requested, can you rewrite your answer to let me understand how I should calculate the address needed to `add-symbol-file`? I need to run _gdb_ in the test machine (which doesn't have `nawk` and other bells and whishes because it's a NAS without a complete/full Linux environment) and I also want to avoid changing the interpreter, if possible. This is a sample, the app that I would like to debug is more complex, of course, but the issue happens on the test machine only, hence I want to debug there.

Comment: Thanks, this works! So, to extract `$address_of_the_first_PT_LOAD` is it correct to use this: `cat /proc/16873/maps | grep "/root/test/test" | awk -F'-' '{print "0x" $1; exit; }'` to retrieve always the first match?

Comment: @virtualdj This will work for most binaries, but can run into trouble if the binary `mmap()s` itself, and that mapping is lower in memory. This is generally an unusual thing to do, but "self aware" binaries (e.g. binaries which symbolize their own crashes) may do that.